# Have input field show blank Instead of [object Object] or {

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, datatables

using jquery datatables - how can I have my input show null

```
data: null,
name: "MillerLite",
render: function (data, type, row) {
    if (type === 'display') {
        return '<input name="MillerLite" value="' + data.toString() + '" />';
    }
    return data;
}
```

I've tried - but this shows [null Null]

```
data: null,
name: "MillerLite",
render: function (data, type, row) {
    if (type === 'display') {
        return '<input name="MillerLite" value="' + data.toString() + '" />';
    }
    return data;
}
```

And also - but this shows a left bracket by default {

```
data: null,
name: "MillerLite",
render: function (data, type, row) {
    if (type === 'display') {
        return '<input name="MillerLite" value="' + JSON.stringify(data) + '" />';
    }
    return JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

Comment: if I remove the .tostring() it shows [object Object]

Comment: `data` is an object representing the data in the current row. You need to access the properties of that object to fill the `value` required, eg. `data.foo`. Without knowing more about what the value of `data` is, we can't really help any further

Comment: what can I provide?  How can I get the value of data?  isn't it null, since I'm setting it to null in the beginning?

Comment: Try `console.log(data)` in the `render` function and let us know what it says

Comment: if I add console.log(data); after the return statement there is nothing in the console?

Comment: add it *before* the return statement....

Comment: "*I'm setting it to null in the beginning*" - these are **two different variables** - the one inside `render:function(data)` is passed by datatables, the one at `data:null` (isn't even a variable) is only used to pass data to datatables

Comment: The value for my two columns I am pulling from Entity Framework display in the console and that's it.  Everything else is null

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and set a new variable to whatever value you want, empty string, "null", etc.:

```
data: null,
name: "MillerLite",
render: function (data, type, row) {

    //let myData = (data === null) ? "" : data;
    // if data is an object:
    let myData = (Object.entries(data).length === 0) ? "" : data;

    if (type === 'display') {
        return '<input name="MillerLite" value="' + myData + '" />';
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I get a dev console error of "Uncaught ReferenceError: isNull is not defined

Comment: apologies getting my syntax mixed up

Comment: The problem is because `data` is an object and is being coerced to a string, not that it's null

Comment: @Michael- still get [object Object]

Comment: okay then check for an empty object with `Object.entries(obj).length === 0`

Comment: Again that's missing the point. The problem has nothing to do with whether the object is empty or not, but how to *access the properties of the object**

Answer (score 0):

This will fill the input with 'null' string if data is null, otherwise it will show data.toString(). If you rather have a JSON representation of data (or something else) just parse it accordingly with e.g. JSON.parse:

```js
data: null,
name: "MillerLite",
render: function (data, type, row) {
    if (type === 'display') {
        return '<input name="MillerLite" value="' + (data ? data.toString() : 'null') + '" />';
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: hah - negative.  That gives me the literal string for value in the input

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? If you have some data you show it's string representation if not you show nothing...

Comment: no I mean the input box shows "${data ? data.toString() : ""}"

Comment: Oh, sorry. Template strings are ES6 and it looks like you are not using a transpiler. I'll update the answer...

Comment: I'm using .net core and mvc

Comment: using your edit - I am back to getting [object Object]

Comment: That is because 'data' is an Object so data.toString() will give [object Object]. What you want to display from that Object (one of it's properties, it's JSON representation) is not clear from your question, but you asked how to display null in case it's null.